# Select multiple items in a slicer

Tags: excel, vba

I have working code which selects single items from a slicer, however it doesn't work for multiple items.

The selection is set up by reading which cells in a range are in bold, and populating an array of strings, STP(46), populating up until STP(k). This works fine.

Then the code is supposed to deselect all items in the slicer which aren't in STP, and select those which are. This works for one selection but not for multiple selections - it erroneously selects all items up until the last item to be selected.

```
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_STP_Name")
    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
        For j = 1 To k
            If .SlicerItems(i).Selected And .SlicerItems(i).Caption <> STP(j) Then .SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
        Next j
    Next i

    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
        For j = 1 To k
            If .SlicerItems(i).Caption = STP(j) Then .SlicerItems(i).Selected = True: Exit For
        Next j
    Next i
End with
```

So instead of selecting, say, the 2nd and 4th item in the slicer, it selects the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th, and deselects the rest.

I need to use a looped technique like this because I need to be able to use this code with multiple slicers with different cache names but the same list of items.

I've looked everywhere, and the code above is even from a solution from another question on here. Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to make the process a little more smooth

```
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_test_id")
    Dim i
    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count

        If .SlicerItems(i).Selected And Not stp.Exists(.SlicerItems(i).Caption) Then
            .SlicerItems(i).Selected = False
        End If

    Next i

    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
        If stp.Exists(.SlicerItems(i).Caption) Then
            .SlicerItems(i).Selected = True
        End If

    Next i
End With
```

I'm not totally clear on why you need the first loop. I'm reading "Then the code is supposed to deselect all items in the slicer which aren't in STP, and select those which are." as "select only those otems in STP and deselect all others" which this reduced code will do:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_test_id")
    Dim i
    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
        .SlicerItems(i).Selected = stp.Exists(.SlicerItems(i).Caption)
    Next i
End With
```

populating the `Dictionary` is super easy

```
Dim stp As New Dictionary
stp.Add "73148", "73148"
stp.Add "73150", "73150"
stp.Add "73159", "73159"
```

You need to reference the `Microsoft Scripting Runtime`

[image: Tools > References]
[image: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll]

note that if you don't see `Microsoft Scripting Runtime` in the list you can Browse to `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\scrrun.dll`

Comment: @GabrielH what line give you the message?

Comment: Thanks Brad, I've implemented the below and it's saying "Object doesn't support this property or method", where have I gone wrong?
    Dim stp2 As New Collection
    stp2.Add "Buckinghamshire, Oxfordshire and Berkshire West", "Buckinghamshire, Oxfordshire and Berkshire West"
    stp2.Add "Cambridgeshire and Peterborough", "Cambridgeshire and Peterborough"

    With ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Slicer_STP_Name")
    For i = 1 To .SlicerItems.Count
        .SlicerItems(i).Selected = stp2.Exists(.SlicerItems(i).Caption)
    Next i
    End With

Comment: The line which gave me the message was

.SlicerItems(i).Selected = stp2.Exists(.SlicerItems(i).Caption)

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote `Collection` and I should have written `Dictionary`

Comment: @GabrielH `Dim stp As New Collection`

Comment: Thanks Brad. When I define it as "Dim stp2 As New Collection" it says "Object doesn't support this property or method" but when I define it as "Dim stp2 As New Dictionary" it says "User defined type not defined". I don't think I have Dictionary on this Excel version?

Comment: @GabrielH You need to reference the Microsoft Scripting Runtime. I'll add a screen shot to the post of how to do that

Comment: Ah yes, got it. Works perfectly and quickly now, thanks so much. My tech levelled up +1!